# Connection to Maria DB from ADF is not getting succeeded

Tags: azure, mariadb, azure-data-factory, mariadb-10.4

I am trying to connect with on-premise MariaDB from the Azure Data Factory.

The IPs are whitelisted from the MariaDB side with self-hosted IR and when we try to connect to the database it throws the timed-out error.

Any idea what could be wrong here? Is there any detailed documentation regarding the MariaDB Connection from ADF?

[image]

[image]
[image]
Tried with port 22 as well as default port 3306.

I had gone through the MS Document and followed the steps to get connected. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-mariadb?tabs=data-factory

Below is the Telnet result from the IR
[image]

Does the whitelisting happen properly and Connection is fine from IR? If yes what could have gone wrong here?

Comment: port 22 is a ssh port.  MariaDB is normally 3306. Try that.

Comment: Tried port 3306 but still getting time out error

Comment: Port 3306 was blocking from MariaDB side. Get it whitelisted and connected. Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ERROR [08001] [Microsoft][MariaDB] (1004) The connection has timed out while connecting to server: **** at port: 22.
```

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59113646/what-is-the-default-port-number-of-mariadb#:%7E:text=The%20default%20port%20number%20for%20both%20MySQL%20and,CentOS%20%2F%20RHEL%29%20and%20restarting%20the%20service%20%3B%29), the default port for MariaDB is **3306**. You have mentioned **22** as the port number. That may be the reason for getting the above error. Once you replace **3306** instead of **22** in the port number, the linked service test connection will be tested successfully, as shown below:

[image]

Comment: was there any firewall blocking at MariaDB server?

Comment: Also I tried with port 3306, still facing the same issue.

Comment: When the MariaDB software is installed, port 3306 is automatically opened. Most client connectors default to port 3306. If you want to connect to a MariaDB instance that has chosen a non-default port, you need to specify that port in the client code when it makes a connection.

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70823615) once.

Comment: Port 3306 was blocking from MariaDB side. Get it whitelisted and connected. Thank You